# How to access data stored in QModelIndex

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The code below create a single `QListView` with the data and proxy models "attached".
Clicking one of the radio buttons calls for `buttonClicked()` function.

This function calls model's `.data(index,role)` method to get the data stored in a current index.

For the `DisplayRole` the model's `.data()` method properly returns the name of index (assigned to it by the time it was created). But when
'ItemDataRole' is used I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: QSortFilterProxyModel.data(QModelIndex, int role=Qt.DisplayRole): argument 2 has unexpected type 'sip.enumtype'
```

--

```
Question 1: How to fix this error?
```

If you take a look at `addItems()` method there is a line there:

```
self.setData(index, 'keyword')
```

Apparently I am trying to set 'keyword' as my own "custom data" (is it what ProxyModel is going to be use while filtering the indexes?).

Question 2: How to query the string "keyword" I've set with `self.setData(index, 'keyword')`?
Is this data accessible or it is "reserved" and can't be queried?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}

class ProxyModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)

class DataModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=[] 
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)):  return QtCore.QVariant()

        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.items[index.row()]

        elif role==QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole:
            return index.data()

    def addItems(self):
        for key in elements:
            index=QtCore.QModelIndex()
            self.setData(index, 'keyword')
            self.beginInsertRows(index, 0, 0)
            self.items.append(key)           

        self.endInsertRows()        

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)        

        self.view=QtGui.QListView()

        self.dataModel=DataModel()        
        self.dataModel.addItems()

        self.proxyModel=ProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.dataModel)
        self.view.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        buttonsLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        animalsButton=QtGui.QRadioButton('Show Animals')
        birdsButton=QtGui.QRadioButton('Show Birds')
        fishButton=QtGui.QRadioButton('Show Fish')
        self.buttons=[animalsButton,birdsButton,fishButton]
        for button in self.buttons:
            button.toggled.connect(self.buttonClicked)
            buttonsLayout.addWidget(button)      
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.insertLayout(1,buttonsLayout)
        self.show()

    def buttonClicked(self,arg=None):
        for button in self.buttons:
            if button.isChecked(): break

        index=self.view.currentIndex()
        print 'Index DisplayRole: %s'%self.view.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole).toString() 
        # print 'ItemDataRole', self.view.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole)    

window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a working example on how to use `QTableView` with `QStandardItemModel` populated with `QStandardItem`s.

A possible advantage of using `QtGui.QStandardItemModel` over `QtCore.QAbstractListModel` is that `QtGui.QStandardItemModel` doesn't have to be sub-classed in order to be assigned to `QTableView`.
You just go ahead and declare it:

```
view=QtGui.QTableView() # declare table view
model=QtGui.QStandardItemModel() # declare model
view.setModel(model) # assign model to table view
```

To create a view-item declare it first:

```
item=QtGui.QStandardItem('My Item Name') # stored 'My Item Name' can be queried using `Qt.DisplayRole` flag
```

Assign a declared `QStandardItem` to view using:

```
model.appendRow(item)
```

`model.appendRow(item)` method "creates" as many `QModelIndex`es as there are columns in a table-view. So there is no need to create `QModelIndex`es manually for each column in a row : the row the item was assigned to.

Next using `item.setData(value,role)` method you can store any type of data using one of pre-defined `QModelIndex` roles such as:

```
item.setData('< Column 0 My Display Value as "DisplayRole" >', QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
item.setData('< Column 0 My Custom Value as "UserRole" >', QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
item.setData('< Column 0 My Custom Value as "UserRole+1" >', QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1)
```

All three assignment-lines above are used to assign three different values to the same "item": first value is a string `'< Column 0 My Display Value as "DisplayRole" >'` which is stored under `Qt.DisplayRole` role (use this role to retrieve it back).

A string value: `'< Column 0 My Custom Value as "UserRole" >'` is stored under `Qt.UserRole`. Use this role to retrieve it back. And etc.

While `item.setData(value,role)` method is quite useful and it does use a simple syntax it is also very limited since it only deals with a single `QModelIndex` stored in a zero column of the row the item is assigned to. In order to be able to store a custom data (or modify an existing data) stored in non-zero columns of the item's row we get the item's row number first:

```
itemRow=item.row()
```

Knowing the item's row-number we can get all the item indexes from every column using
in a "manual" mode:

```
indexOfColumn1=model.index(itemRow, 1)
indexOfColumn2=model.index(itemRow, 2)
```

(where a second integer argument such as `1` or `2` are the column numbers).

Or in a "fully automatic" mode:

```
for i in range(model.columnCount()):
    eachColumnIndex=model.index(itemRow, i)
```

Knowing the item's `QModelIndexes` we can use them to query or store data just like we did using `item.setData()` method (a method that only assigns/retreives a data from/to a zero-column `QModelIndex`).

In order to store and retreive the data in each-column-`QModelIndex` we have to use `model.setData(index,value,role)` and `model.data(index, role)` methods (it appears we can't get/set the data using `QModelIndex` instance directly... like this:

`myIndex.setData(value,role)` - this is invalid code since `QModelIndex` doesn't come with `.setData()` method.

In order to retrieve the data stored per `QModelIndex` we use `model.data(index,role)`:

```
model=view.model()
print model.data(index, QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1).toPyObject()
```

For a single column views (such as `.QListView`) dealing with supplied `QStandardItem` methods would be probably sufficient. But for multi-column views (such as `QTabLeView` there is a chance the individual column's `QModelIndexe`s would have to be accessed.

[image]

```
import os,sys
home=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(home,'site-packages'))
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
class Window(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__() 
        model=QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Column 0','Column 1','Column 3'])
        for i in range(3):
            item=QtGui.QStandardItem('Column 0 Item %s'%i)
            item.setData('< Column 0 Custom Value as "UserRole" >', QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            item.setData('< Column 0 Custom Value as "UserRole+1" >', QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1)
            model.appendRow(item)

            itemRow=item.row()
            indexOfColumn1=model.index(itemRow, 1)
            indexOfColumn2=model.index(itemRow, 2)

            model.setData(indexOfColumn1, 'Column 1 Item', QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            model.setData(indexOfColumn1, '< Column 1 Custom Value as "UserRole" >', QtCore.Qt.UserRole)

            model.setData(indexOfColumn2, 'Column 2 Item', QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            model.setData(indexOfColumn2, '< Column 2 Custom Value as "UserRole" >', QtCore.Qt.UserRole)

        self.setModel(model)
        self.clicked.connect(self.onClick)  
        self.show()

    def onClick(self,index=None):
        row=index.row()
        column=index.column()

        model=self.model()
        indexOfColumn0=model.index(row, 0)
        indexOfColumn1=model.index(row, 1)
        indexOfColumn2=model.index(row, 2)
        print indexOfColumn0==index, indexOfColumn1==index, indexOfColumn2==index


        print  'ROW: %s  COLUMN: %s'%(row,column)
        print 'DispayRoleData via self.model().data(index,role): "%s"'%self.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole).toString()
        print 'UserRoleData via self.model().data(index,role): "%s"'%self.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toPyObject()
        print 'UserRoleData via self.model().data(index,role): "%s"'%self.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1).toPyObject()      

        for key in self.model().itemData(index):
            print 'self.model.itemData(index):    key: %s  value: %s'%(key, self.model().itemData(index)[key].toString())

        item=self.model().itemFromIndex(index)


window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The 'limitations' you talk about don't really exist. The limitations to your example are there because you only add one item to the row. You should be creating one `QStandardItem` for each column, putting them in a list, and adding the list. Eg. `model.appendRow([item_for_col_1, item_for_col_2, item_for_col_3])`. You can then call `item_for_col_x.setData` on each item however you like. If you need access to the items later, you can either store a reference to them yourself, or use methods like `indexToItem()` or `itemToIndex()` (possibly constructing your own QModelIndex if necessary).

Comment: One final thing I will add is that while `QModelIndex`s become invalid (for instance when or add/delete from the model), items do not. So it is safe to use the item to find the index whenever you want, as long as you don't persist in using the index after the first subsequent call which modifies the model in any way.