# Multiple models crash

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

A code below create a window with `QListView` on a left side and `QTableView` on a right.
Using `.setModel()` `QListView` was assigned `ListModel` and `QTableView` was assigned `TableModel`.
On a window start-up only a List View gets populated with the items. A right-table-view gets populated only when left-side-list-view gets clicked.

[image]

Question: Why this code crashes? Is it because two models in use in the same time?

[image]

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}
class ListModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self) 
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items) 
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1        
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        key=str(self.items[index.row()])
        if role==QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return key
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return key

    def addItem(self, key=None, column=0):
        totalItems=self.rowCount()+1
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), totalItems, column)
        self.items.append(str(key))
        self.endInsertRows()

    def buildItems(self):
        for key in elements:
            self.addItem(key) 

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 4
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return key 

    def addItem(self, each=None, column=0):
        totalItems=self.rowCount()+1
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), totalItems, column)
        self.items.append(str(each))
        self.endInsertRows()

    def rebuildItems(self, index):
        key = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        if not key: return
        key=str(key.toString())
        for each in elements[key]:
            self.addItem(str(each)) 

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout) 
        self.dataModel=ListModel()
        self.dataModel.buildItems() 
        self.dataModelB=TableModel()
        self.viewA=QtGui.QListView()
        self.viewA.setModel(self.dataModel)
        self.viewA.clicked.connect(self.onClick) 
        self.viewB=QtGui.QTableView()         
        self.viewB.setModel(self.dataModelB)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewB)    
        self.show()
    def onClick(self, index):
        self.viewB.model().rebuildItems(index)

window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## EDITED LATER:

Below is a fixed code. In the original example the problem was caused by improper usage of `.beginInsertRows()` method. I mistakenly thought that the last argument to be supplied is a column number. But according to the documentation (thanks to three_pineapples for pointing out) the last argument should be the last row-number to be inserted.

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}
class ListModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self) 
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items) 
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1        
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        key=str(self.items[index.row()])
        if role==QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return key
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return key

    def addItem(self, key=None):
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self.items.append(str(key))
        self.endInsertRows()

    def buildItems(self):
        for key in elements:
            self.addItem(key) 

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 4
    def data(self, index, role):
        key=str(self.items[index.row()])
        column=index.column()

        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if not column:  return key 
            else:
                print key, column, elements.get(key,{}).get(column)
                return elements.get(key,{}).get(column)

    def rebuildItems(self, index):
        key=index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toString()  

        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self.items.append(key)
        self.endInsertRows()

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout) 
        self.dataModel=ListModel()
        self.dataModel.buildItems() 
        self.dataModelB=TableModel()
        self.viewA=QtGui.QListView()
        self.viewA.setModel(self.dataModel)
        self.viewA.clicked.connect(self.onClick) 
        self.viewB=QtGui.QTableView()         
        self.viewB.setModel(self.dataModelB)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewB)    
        self.show()
    def onClick(self, index):
        self.viewB.model().rebuildItems(index)

window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you provide more details of crash? In which row of the code it happens?

Comment: On OSX: 10.7.5, Python: 2.7.1, Qt: 5.2.0, SIP: 4.15.4, PyQt: 4.10.4 it crashes as soon as a left-side-list-view's item is clicked.

Comment: You are using Qt5 with PyQt4? Unless you just made a typo, that doesn't seem wise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your crash on PyQt v4.11.1, 32-bit Python 2.7, Windows 8.1.

However, your TableModel implementation is completely broken, so presumably that would explain why it crashes on your Mac?

Specifically:

- The signature for `beginInsertRows` appears to be wrong. It doesn't follow the documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) (linked to from the `QAbstractTableModel` page [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstracttablemodel.html#subclassing)). The signature is not `beginInsertRows(parent, row, column)` but rather `beginInsertRows(parent, row, numRows)`.
- The value for the row you are inserting to should be `self.rowCount()` as row indexing starts from 0. So when you have 0 items in your model, you insert to row 0 (the first row). When you have 1 item in your model, you insert into row 1 (the second row), etc.
- The `TableModel.data()` method is broken. Specifically it appears to be missing the line `key=str(self.items[index.row()])`

My question would be, since you seem to be having trouble with models quite regularly (I feel like I've seen many questions on here from you in regards to implementing a custom model), why aren't you using the predefined Qt model [`QStandardItemModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html) which does all of the complex stuff for you? (You don't need to subclass it to use it)

If you want help translating the example you've posted above to using `QStandardItemModel`, please post a new question. I'm sure either I or someone else will answer it quickly.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I have been using `.beginInsertRows(parent, first_row_number_to_insert, last_row_number_to_insert)` wrong. I thought the last arg should be a column. Knowing it I've fixed a code. And it works now like a charm! Thanks again!

Comment: Few days ago I made a post on my take on `QStandardItemModel`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25985721/1107049   I do like "it does all the complex stuff for me". Using 'QtCore.QAbstractTableModel` I am trying to avoid a possible limitations imposed by `QStandardItemModel`. Since "I will do all the complex stuff for you" mode probably comes with some side effects. Doesn't it?

Comment: I've just posted a question which is a logical continuation of what was started here. A link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26067068/1107049  Would be interesting to hear your opinion.