# How to sync multiple views sharing same model

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

A left-side-list-view click populates a right-side-table-view with the corresponding to a clicked item items. The problem is that a right-side-table-view items list keeps growing with every left-side-view click. 
I can go ahead and clear a right-side view from all the items on every left-side-view click s with:

```
for i in range(self.rowCount()):
    self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), i, i)
    self.endRemoveRows()
```

But that would require re-creating the right-side-view items again and again (even for those clicked items that were already created earlier (and then deleted).

I wonder if there is a way to create only those right-side-view items that were never created. And instead of deleting them on a left-side-view click: hiding them to unhide later when a corresponding left-side-view item is clicked again.

Please avoid a short non-descriptive phrases or keywords. Instead post the example code showing clearly how it could be achieved. Once again, the goal is to display in a right-side view a list of only those animals whose type is clicked using a left side-view.

[image]

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}
class ListModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self) 
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items) 
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1        
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        key=str(self.items[index.row()])
        if role==QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return key
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return key

    def addItem(self, key=None):
        totalItems=self.rowCount()
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), totalItems, totalItems)
        self.items.append(str(key))
        self.endInsertRows()

    def buildItems(self):
        for key in elements:
            self.addItem(key) 

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 4
    def data(self, index, role):
        key=str(self.items[index.row()])
        column=index.column()

        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if not column:  return key 
            else:
                print key, column, elements.get(key,{}).get(column)
                return elements.get(key,{}).get(column)

    def rebuildItems(self, index):
        key=index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toString()  
        totalItems=self.rowCount()

        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), totalItems, totalItems)
        self.items.append(key)
        self.endInsertRows()

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout) 
        self.dataModel=ListModel()
        self.dataModel.buildItems() 
        self.dataModelB=TableModel()
        self.viewA=QtGui.QListView()
        self.viewA.setModel(self.dataModel)
        self.viewA.clicked.connect(self.onClick) 
        self.viewB=QtGui.QTableView()         
        self.viewB.setModel(self.dataModelB)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewB)    
        self.show()
    def onClick(self, index):
        self.viewB.model().rebuildItems(index)

window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## EDITED LATER:

Working example of model/proxy setup:

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}
class ListModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self) 
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items) 
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1        
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        key=str(self.items[index.row()])
        if role==QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return key
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return key

    def addItem(self, key=None):
        totalItems=self.rowCount()
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), totalItems, totalItems)
        self.items.append(str(key))
        self.endInsertRows()

    def buildItems(self):
        for key in elements:
            self.addItem(key) 

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 4
    def data(self, index, role):
        key=str(self.items[index.row()])
        column=index.column()

        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if not column:  return key 
            else:           return elements.get(key,{}).get(column)

    def rebuildItems(self, index):
        key=index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toString() 
        if key in self.items: return

        totalItems=self.rowCount()        
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), totalItems, totalItems)
        self.items.append(key)
        self.endInsertRows()

class ProxyTableModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProxyTableModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def headerData(self, column, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return QtCore.QVariant(int(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter))
            return QtCore.QVariant(int(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter))
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation==QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return QtCore.QVariant("Species %s"%column)

        return QtCore.QVariant(int(column + 1))

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout) 
        listModel=ListModel()
        listModel.buildItems() 

        tableModel=TableModel()
        proxyTableModel=ProxyTableModel()
        proxyTableModel.setSourceModel(tableModel)
        proxyTableModel.setFilterKeyColumn(0)    

        self.viewA=QtGui.QListView()
        self.viewA.setModel(listModel)
        self.viewA.clicked.connect(self.onClick) 
        self.viewB=QtGui.QTableView()         
        self.viewB.setModel(proxyTableModel)
        self.viewB.setColumnHidden(0,True)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewB)    
        self.show()
    def onClick(self, index):
        self.viewB.model().sourceModel().rebuildItems(index)

        key=index.data().toString()
        self.viewB.model().setFilterRegExp(key)

window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## EDITED #2

[image]

Here is a working code based on the suggestions made by **mdurant** (many thanks!). Instead of using a `proxy model` (to filter the display content of right-side-view) an existing index is used (to keep things for this example simpler I switched right-side-view to QListView).

---

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
elements={'Animals':{0:'Bison',1:'Panther',2:'Elephant',3:'Dog'},'Birds':{0:'Duck',1:'Hawk',2:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{0:'Shark',1:'Salmon'}}
class ListModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self) 
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items) 
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1        
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        key=str(self.items[index.row()])
        if role==QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return key
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return key

    def addItem(self, key=None):
        totalItems=self.rowCount()
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), totalItems, totalItems)
        self.items.append(str(key))
        self.endInsertRows()

    def buildItems(self):
        for key in elements:
            self.addItem(key) 

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.key=None
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):   
        if not self.items:   return 0
        else: return len(self.items) 

    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 2

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()       
        if not self.key: return QtCore.QVariant() 

        row=index.row()
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return elements.get(self.key,{}).get(row)

    def rebuildItems(self, index):        
        self.key=str(index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toString())

        self.items=elements[self.key].keys()
        self.reset()

        self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(1,1), self.index(1,4))

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout) 
        self.dataModel=ListModel()
        self.dataModel.buildItems() 

        self.viewA=QtGui.QListView()
        self.viewA.setModel(self.dataModel)
        self.viewA.clicked.connect(self.onClick) 

        self.viewB=QtGui.QListView()         
        self.dataModelB=TableModel()   

        self.viewB.setModel(self.dataModelB)
        # self.viewB.setColumnHidden(0,True)        

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewB)    
        self.show()

    def onClick(self, index):
        self.viewB.model().rebuildItems(index)

window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you asked, as far as not repeating insertions:

```
def rebuildItems(self, index):
    key=index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
    totalItems=self.rowCount()
    if not key in self.items:
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), totalItems, totalItems)
        self.items.append(key)
        self.endInsertRows()
```

However, for hiding items, that is something done by the view (or a proxy model), not the model itself.

Comment: ...but I do wish I understood what you were trying to achieve here.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to have a model with an instance variable that holds the current selected row, and in row 1 display that item's information - the model stays 1-row long always.

Comment: I want both views to share the same `elements` variable. So when there is a change made to the data both views are updated automatically. The left view shows the list of items. while the right-side-view displays the sub-items...let's say a left-view is used to list all the book-titles. Clicking a single book-title in left-side view displays this book's chapters in a right-side view. Do I implement it correctly? Should a single model used or mutlitple models? I plan to use a third view which would display sub-sub-items when a "Chapters" view is clicked it would display the pages and etc..

Answer (score 2):

Now with single row. This row could be hidden when nothing has been selected yet - I just show it as empty.

```
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    sel = None

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 4
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return 
        key=self.sel
        column=index.column()
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if not column:  return str(key)
            else:
                return elements.get(key,{}).get(column) if (self.sel is not None) else QtCore.QVariant()

    def rebuildItems(self, index):
        key=index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        if not key in self.items:
            self.items.append(key)
        self.sel = key
        self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(1,1), self.index(1,4) )

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout) 
        self.dataModel=ListModel()
        self.dataModel.buildItems() 
        self.dataModelB=TableModel()
        self.viewA=QtGui.QListView()
        self.viewA.setModel(self.dataModel)
        self.viewA.clicked.connect(self.onClick) 
        self.viewB=QtGui.QTableView()         
        self.viewB.setModel(self.dataModelB)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewB)    
        self.show()
    def onClick(self, index):
        self.viewB.model().rebuildItems(index)
```

Comment: Let me see it... meanwhile please take a look at the code i posted under my original question in "EDITED LATER" section. It uses proxymodel to filter the right-side-view items from a display based on what is selected in a left-side-display...

Comment: OK - but looks rather complicated for the current task. I hope your use case justifies it. Note that the data is more naturally described by a tree, rather than list/table.

Comment: A question after reading your example. `self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(1,1), self.index(1,4))` -  what method is triggered with this line?

Comment: It is an internal signal, which tells the views to redisplay their data between those indices. If you leave it out, there won't be a repaint until the display changes for some other reason (such as resize).

Comment: So we command to redraw view by emitting `dataChanged` signal! That's great to know! Please take a look at the section "EDITED #2" in my original question. I modified your code into the original question-example-code. Unfortunately, the right-side view is not redrawing...

Comment: I just posted a screenshot of the window. The right-side-table-view comes with one empty row straight from the window start-up (even before left-side-view is clicked). That happens because `TableModel.rowCount()` always returns `1` (should probably `return len(self.items)` instead. Then in `TableModel.rebuildItems()` you use `self.beginInsertRows(index,0,0)` without never calling `self.endInsertRows()` How does it work for you? Please post an entire code the way you run it. So I could test it on my machine...

Comment: In your answer you use: `self.beginInsertRows(index,0,0)` where `index` is an index that was submitted as an argument to `TableModel.rebuildItems()` by `onClick()` function. That submitted `index` "belongs" to different `ListModel` model. Yet, `TableModel` with its `.rebuildItems()` goes ahead and inserts the rows using `.beginInsertRows()`. Is it intentional?

Comment: you don't need insertRows at all, sorry, unless you want to start with a blank table (no empty row).

Comment: If we don't need  `insertRows` then why it is used in `rebuildItems()`: `self.beginInsertRows(index,0,0)`? Please edit your answer if there is a type there.